# Using an excel calculator to generate a column of data for large scale analysis

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm currently trying to do some large scale analysis (10,000 rows) which relies upon a 'calculator' someone has built within my organisation within excel. The hitch is that the underlying calculations within the calculator are hidden, and are not available to me so I can't just reproduce these steps to create a column with the calculator output.

It seems that the only way for me to populate this column would be to manually complete the calculator for each entry and type it across which is unfeasible for this much data. I'm therefore wondering whether there exists a tool or a way of automating this process (perhaps a macro) so that my analysis file will just plug in the calculator inputs for each data point and return the output to a fresh column?

I have some limited experience with macros and python - so would appreciate answers focussed around using one of these if possible

Comment: We need more information to help.  How does this "calculator" in Excel work?  Is it a form that opens or is it built into a sheet?

Comment: This question is too broad right now. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)